# HTTP method for both sending and returning information

Tags: rest, http

I'm building a web application that needs to process some information on a server. There is no database involved, the server (using Flask) just needs to receive some (complex) information, process it, and send back the result.

My question is which HTTP method is most suitable here (if any). When I read about HTTP methods, they are usually explained in terms of a REST api, where a `GET` request is used to retrieve data from the server and a `POST` request is used to create new data on the server. In my case however, I don't need to store any information on the server. A `GET` request doesn't seem suitable here, as the information sent to the server is rather complex, and can't be easily encoded in the URL. I think a `POST` request should work here, as I can send the data in JSON format, but the specifications say `POST` should be used when you want to create something on the server, and a response should only contain a success message and/or location.

Am I missing something here? Should I use something different like WebSocket, or is a `POST` request fine here, although it doesn't abide by the REST principles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...but the specifications say POST should be used when you want to create something on the server, and a response should only contain a success message and/or location...." - exactly what specs say that?

Answer (score 1):

> the specifications say POST should be used when you want to create something on the server

No, they don't.  A lot of *people* say that, but the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) is not so restrictive.

> The POST method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics

Here's how [Roy Fielding explained it](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) in 2009:

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

Yes, POST isn't ideal - the semantics of POST are neither safe nor idempotent, and your particular case would benefit from communicating those properties to general purpose components.

But it is good enough, until the work is done to standardize the semantics of a new method token that better handles this case.

Answer (score 0):

We use `POST` method to send data to the server. What the server does with the data is encoded in the server logic.

As a client if you want to just send data to server use `POST`.